# Cloud build: No permission for signining blobs even though I granted them

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to build a Java application in cloud build and deploy it to Cloud Run.

[image]

1. I have granted rights to cloud build service account to write blobs

2. Morover, I have changed default service account for Cloud Run instance, with rights to write blobs.

I'm letting instance figure out service account by doing: `FirebaseApp.initializeApp();`

When I run my tests, I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error code 403 trying to sign provided bytes: The caller does not have permission
    at com.second.hand.security.jwt.TokenProviderTest.testReturnFalseWhenJWTisMalformed(TokenProviderTest.java:75)
```

If I print `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()`, in Cloud build logs I get `ComputeEngineCredentials{...`, although I changed Service Account to a different one.

In my local environment, it prints `applicationDefaultServiceAccountCredentials{...` as expected, since I set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environmental variable

What am I doing wrong? I'm out of ideas

Comment: Why do you try to perform a firebase init in Cloud Build. it's sounds strange not?

Comment: I'm trying to modify my API in the way that supports custom tokens in the specification that Firebase requires https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: Ok, but why in Cloud Build??